# Base URL is non-www which results in routes non-www

Tags: laravel, nginx, dns, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Laravel 8 project running on an Nginx Webserver in a Docker container through an Nginx Reverse Proxy.

So DNS -> Reverse Proxy -> Docker Webserver container -> PHP-FPM container

The problem is that when I use Laravel's `route()` it is **missing the www** resulting in login not working (as well as assets etc).
Because I AM on the www domain (because of Nginx redirect) but the route endpoint is non-www (so a different site, token issue I believe).

In my .env I have APP_URL set which I believe is only for CLI commands and additionally I have ASSET_URL set, which works for the `asset()` functions. I should not have to use ASSET_URL if the source of the problem, my setup, is correct (which it clearly is not).

I CAN bypass the problem by using `URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));` in my router, that forces the APP_URL set in my .env to be used in the `RouteUrlGenerator` (I believe)

Output of `\URL::to('/')` is https://example.com, so NON-WWW (obv. WITHOUT using `URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));`)
Even though my browser's URL is including www, so https://www.example.com/blabla.

I would say something is wrong in my setup, either my DNS, Nginx Reverse Proxy, or Nginx Webserver configs but I can't figure out what it is...
I hope it is just a simple redirect fix somehow.
I have also already restarted my servers etc and done a `php artisan optimize:clear` and also `config:cache` and `config:clear` to be sure.

Please find below my configs:

**DNS via CloudFlare** (proxied):

```
A      example.com  123.123.123.123  Proxied
A      www          123.123.123.123  Proxied
CNAME  *            example.com      DNS Only
```

My **Nginx Reverse Proxy** config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name     example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:8012;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
}
```

My **Nginx webserver** config:

```
server {
#    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
#    listen 80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9012;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/example.com.au/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    
   # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs & enable Gzip compression:
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

My "default" Laravel 8 **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My **.env**:

```
APP_NAME=SomeSite.com
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:sdljkldasjkasjasdjklaslkasd
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://www.example.com#Used for CLI function such as artisan...
#ASSET_URL=https://asseturl.test#Only used in asset()
TRUSTPROXIES=*
...
```

Comment: I used to have a similar issue and everything was set up correctly. Finally, I found out that the wrong (www vs non-www) redirect was cached in the browser itself. Try clearing your browser cache or completely unused browser. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: Thanks, good point but I've tried it with IE (which I never use) and the same issue.
The URL logs https://example.com as the base URL, the route() is missing the www (for example `route('password.request')`.
I have ofc. also already restated the servers etc

Comment: In your .env APP_URL you have url with 'www', right?

Comment: correct, I have also updated my question with my .env

Comment: try to "rm bootstrap/cache/config.php" or "php artisan config:clear" inside docker container

Comment: What's output of: docker exec <YOUR_CONTAINER_ID> php artisan tinker --execute "echo config('app.url') . ' ' . env('APP_URL');"

Comment: I have already deleted all the config via `rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*` and the output of the command is: `https://www.example.com https://www.example.com<aside>â</aside>` executed from within my PHP-FPM container

Comment: Got a feeling the problem is really in the Nginx config somehow

Comment: hm, CF and Nginx config looks also alright

Comment: There are disabled "Listen 80" lines in Nginx webserver config. Shouldn't they be enabled?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but I would move 301 redirect (non-www => www) to reverse-proxy nginx.

Comment: @MartinOsusky champion!! Can you post that as the answer please? Moving the 301 redirect from my Nginx Webserver to my Nginx Reverse Proxy did the trick!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is moving the 301 redirect from **Nginx Webserver** to **Nginx Reverse Proxy** (superior level).

This is the following part of the configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Edit: I suspect it's related to the part:

```
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
```

Comment: Awesome! Yes this was the right solution!
I must add that I only commented out the listen on port 80 for testing purpose, indeed I think this should be there as well.
Maybe update this in your answer!
Again, thank you very much!

So yes, now URL() also returns `https://www.example.com`

Comment: would you mind changing my website address to example.com, I forgot to comment it out :D

Comment: I still wonder why :D I mean to me it is like doing `[www or non-www] > proxy [www or non-www] > webserver: [non-www = www] > php` vs `[www or non-www] > proxy [non-www = www] > webserver [www] > php`